# C# WPF DataGrid сортировка

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Как сделать чтобы последняя строка в DataGrid не сортировался вместе с остальными?
На пример все строки сортируются по возрастанию, а последняя не зависимо от знания остается в конце.

Comment: Запомнить во временную переменную последнюю строку, удалить последнюю строку, сделать сортировку, вставить из переменной последнюю строку в конец.

Comment: @Bulson не подскажите какой обработчик отвечает за нажатие на заголовок?

Comment: я так сразу и не вспомню... надо гуглить